# Copy a webpage into Word or other word processor

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, asp.net-2.0

I'm working on a web app in ASP.NET (2.0) in which the user needs to be able to copy a bunch of content from a page into a word processor like MS Word in order to use it in a brochure or handout of some sort.

It appears that simply selecting content on a page to copy and paste does not always work well.  For example, Word doesn't seem to receive any style info that was achieved via classes and not inline styles.  And programmatically creating a Word document looks complicated and limits me to one client word processor.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I find copying a web page from Internet Explorer has better results than other browsers.

You may have luck using a "Word Print Driver" so users just print to word. Especially if the webpage has a print version either via a new page or they are using a CSS print stylesheet.

I have never used one but this search result seems to suggest that you can get one.

http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=print+to+word+printer+driver

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into the Winnovative HTML to PDF converter. You can just pass it a URL and it will convert it into a PDF. PDFs are generally better for that type of content anyway.

http://www.winnovative-software.com/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Valamas.  The best way to handle this type of request is to do a print to file and use CSS.  Just set the media tag in your Link to the CSS file to print (which is set to screen by default).